# How do I save an object's field to a string

Tags: c#

**Question: How do I store an object's value into a string?**

**objGet holds:**

```
public string name { get; set; }
```

**Get information + convert object field to a string**

```
objGet thisIsTheObject;
string storageString;
```

**How would I store name into storageString?**
I've tried the following:

```
storageString = thisIsTheObject.name;
```

I just get the following error:
**Error:** Use of unassigned local variable

Comment: try assigning a value to name property before rtying to get its value

Answer (score 3):

That error means you are trying to use an object which is not initialized. May be you forgot to initialize the objGet class object.

This will initialize the object with a valid instance

```
objGet thisIsTheObject=new objGet();
thisIsTheObject.name="set your value";
```

Assuming you have default contructor avalilabe for this class.

Now you are good to access the object property values

Answer (score 2):

have you initialised objGet?

```
objGet thisIsTheObject = new objGet() { name = "The name" };
string storageString = thisIsTheObject.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

An `object` needs to be instantiated before its use and its fields initialized:

```
objGet thisIsTheObject = new objGet(); 
thisIsTheObject.name = "Your_String_Value"; 
....
....
string storageString = thisIsTheObject.name;
```

this means that your class need an empty constructor

```
public class objGet
{
    public objGet() { }
    public string name { get; set; }    
}
```